# SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' when a ';' is there after convert JSONArray to JavaScript array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsp

I created JSONArray in java looks like below:

```java
array = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < master.size(); i++) {
    Map option = (Map) master.get(i);

    String key = (String) option.get("KEY");
    String text = key + ": " + (String) option.get("NAME");

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("key", modalityKey);
    object.put("text", text);
    array.add(object);
}
```

Then I use `var list = "<%=array%>";` in JavaScript, but I got error SCRIPT1004, the data in list on IE F12 console as below, I am not sure where has mistake, please help me.

```
var list = "[
{"key":"C","text":"C: C1"},
{"key":"E","text":"E: E2"},
{"key":"G","text":"G: G3"},
{"key":"H","text":"H: H4"},
{"key":"I","text":"I: I5"},
{"key":"K","text":"K: K6"},
{"key":"L","text":"L: L7"},
{"key":"N","text":"N: N8"},
{"key":"P","text":"P: P9"},
{"key":"Q","text":"Q: Q10"},
{"key":"R","text":"R: R11R"},
{"key":"S","text":"S: S12"},
{"key":"T","text":"T: T13"},
{"key":"U","text":"U: U14"},
{"key":"V","text":"V: V15"},
{"key":"X","text":"X: X16"},
{"key":"Y","text":"Y: Y17"},
{"key":"Z","text":"Z: Z18"}]";
```

Comment: multi-line strings don't work in javascript

Comment: There is a difference between Java and JavaScript

Comment: Not to mention unescaped `"` even if it was in a single string.

Comment: Just use `var list = <%=array%>;` without the quotes. Or `var list = JSON.parse(<%=escapeJsString(array)%>);` (whatever `escapeJsString` is in Java)

Comment: @Jaramanda and Jonathan: this has nothing to do with multiline or not. Even in a single line it would be invalid, as the string contains unescaped quotes.

Comment: true @Bergi - first glance and all that :p

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for your help, please answer it.

Answer (score -1):

Change the int to var in:

```
for (int i = 0; i < master.size(); i++) {}
```

new code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < master.size(); i++) {}
```

remember i or index is a variable not integer(int).

Comment: It's fine, this is actually a Java question.

Comment: First code block in question is Java code. Second code block is JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, sorry im based on you Question :(